# im working on a django project as a total beginner . block content end block is not working and the browser renders raw code

Tags: python, html, django, rendering

here is my directory ![workspace]

.core
---templates
-- core
- base.html
-frontpage.html

![base.html]

```
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}Djangochat</title>
```

![frontpage.html]

```
  {% extends 'core/base.html' %}
  {% block title %}Welcome | {% endblock %}
```

![urls.py]

```
  urlpatterns = [
                 path('frontpage', views.frontpage, name='frontpage'),
                ]
```

![views.py]

```
  def frontpage(request):
return render(request, 'core/frontpage.html')
```

output im getting is the raw code itself :

```
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
```

i tryed removing spaces within block tags ..but nothing works , the raw django code is displayed in the browser. what am i missing? . can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Don't post code as images. (And if you have to post images make sure the links are not empty text.)

Comment: And it looks like you are missing spaces in your tags.

Comment: you are accessing template html  instead of view URL, go through tutorial again https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the HTML page in the wrong way. The Django template engine does not render the HTML files this way.

1. You need to define a URL in `urls.py` of `chatapp`:

   ```py
   urlpatterns = [
       path('frontpage/', views.frontpage_view, name='frontpage_view')
   ]
   ```
2. Create a function in `views.py` of `chatapp`:

   ```py
   from django.shortcuts import render

   def frontpage_view(request):
       return render(request, 'chatapp/frontpage.html')
   ```
3. Run the app using the command:

   ```
   python manage.py runserver
   ```
4. Visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/frontpage/` in your browser.